# Passing a function pointer into a constructor C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, game-engine

I'm trying to make a decision tree for my program in which every node has a similar branching function but a different body in the branching method.  I've figured out how to get function pointers into the method but now it seems to not want to take the pointer to method outside of the class.

**This is my node class**

```
class FighterDecisionTreeNode :
public IDecisionTreeNode
{
private:

    FighterDecisionTreeNode* posChild;
    FighterDecisionTreeNode* negChild;
    DecisionFunction *decisionFunc;

public:

    FighterDecisionTreeNode(DecisionFunction *decisionFunction);
   ~FighterDecisionTreeNode(void);
    FighterDecisionTreeNode* getChild(bool child);
    bool getBranch(SpaceObject* object, SpaceObject* thisShip);
    IDecisionTreeNode* makeDecision(SpaceObject* object, SpaceObject* thisShip);
};





FighterDecisionTreeNode::FighterDecisionTreeNode(DecisionFunction * decisionFunction)
{
    decisionFunc = decisionFunction;
}


FighterDecisionTreeNode::~FighterDecisionTreeNode(void)
 {
 }

 FighterDecisionTreeNode* FighterDecisionTreeNode::getChild(bool child)
{

   if(child)
    {
        return posChild;
    }
   else
    {
       return negChild;
    }
}

 IDecisionTreeNode* FighterDecisionTreeNode::makeDecision(SpaceObject* object, SpaceObject* thisShip)
 {
     return getChild(getBranch(object, thisShip))->makeDecision(object,thisShip);
 }


 bool FighterDecisionTreeNode::getBranch(SpaceObject* object, SpaceObject* thisShip)
 {
    return decisionFunc(object, thisShip);
 }
```

**This is my tree class**

```
class FighterDecisionTree:
    public IDecisionTree
{
private:
    //decision methods
    bool isEnemy(SpaceObject* enemy, SpaceObject* ship);

   //decision nodes
    FighterDecisionTreeNode * isEnemyNode;
 public:
    FighterDecisionTree(void);
    virtual ~FighterDecisionTree(void);

    bool getBranch(SpaceObject* object);
    virtual IDecisionTreeNode* makeDecision();

 };




FighterDecisionTree::FighterDecisionTree(void)
{
   isEnemyNode = new FighterDecisionTreeNode( &isEnemy );
}


FighterDecisionTree::~FighterDecisionTree(void)
{
}

IDecisionTreeNode* FighterDecisionTree::makeDecision(){
    return NULL;
}

bool FighterDecisionTree::getBranch(SpaceObject* object)
{
   return false;
}

// I need to pass a condition to each seperate node,
//but each must have a seperate condition

bool FighterDecisionTree::isEnemy(SpaceObject* enemy, SpaceObject* ship)
{
   return true;
}
```

**This is the interface the node class is using**

```
  class IDecisionTreeNode
 {
 private:
   //This is for creating the BST
   //IDecisionTreeNode* posChild;
   //IDecisionTreeNode* negChild;

 public:
    typedef bool (DecisionFunction)(SpaceObject* enemy, SpaceObject* ship);
    IDecisionTreeNode(void);
    IDecisionTreeNode(DecisionFunction *decisionFunction);
   ~IDecisionTreeNode(void);


   virtual IDecisionTreeNode* makeDecision(SpaceObject* object, SpaceObject* thisShip)=0;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add an extra 4 spaces of indentation to the beginning of each line of code so it shows up properly.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. The chances are slim that anybody is willing to read code that looks like this (no, i am not talking about the 4 extra spaces for each line).

Comment: Sorry, I went to sign up and all of my formatting somehow got screwed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any messing with function pointers in your code, so I'm going to attempt to answer best from what I can glean from the question.

> it seems to not want to take the pointer to method outside of the class

My psychic debugging powers sense that you're trying to create pointers to **class methods**. If so, you don't have a plain function pointer, you have a member function pointer. Member function pointers have their own special syntax, because a member function is designed to run in the context of a `this` parameter, which is an implicit part of that function.

It sounds like what you're trying to do would be better served by the **strategy pattern**, or by making the different things you want to do into plain functions, rather than member functions. C++ doesn't require everything to be in a class, and there's really no reason to program such that everything is in a class ;)

Comment: Additionally, function objects would likely be a better solution to the problem he is trying to solve (instead of function pointers).

Comment: @Zac: If he was writing templates or something of that sort I would agree. However, he's not working with templates, which makes passing functors difficult.